# A heat map animation of daily deaths

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate

I have a data frame that has columns Region, Date, and Deaths, and I've imported the package "maps" and its 50 state map.

All of the examples I've seen ask me to `merge()` the data with the map.  However, when I do this merging, I manage to end up with an object of over 4 million rows.

The daily data is in `melted8` and then `melted9`.

Because of the huge size of the `merge()`, the `animate()` step takes a long time to run... in fact I cut it short after 10 minutes.  I do not know if my `ggplot()` is correctly made, but it is also huge (240 mb).

Is there a more reasonably-sized object I could give to `ggplot()`, and am I giving `ggplot()` the right instructions?

```
# a sample
melted8[sample(nrow(melted8), 5), ]

region      date    deaths
<chr>       <int>   <dbl>
arizona     214 7.2815030
missouri    287 0.0000000
arkansas    160 0.3313668
mississippi 53  0.0000000
new jersey  300 0.7880939
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)
library(maps)

us.map <- map_data("state")      #50 state map from library(maps)
melted9 <- merge(us.map, melted8, by="region", all.x=T)

d <- ggplot(melted9) +
  geom_polygon(aes(long,lat, group = group), color='white', fill=NA, data=us.map) +
  geom_polygon(aes(long,lat, group = group, fill = deaths), color = "white") +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray65", high = "red") +
  labs(title = "Deaths per Day") +
  ease_aes("linear")

a <- animate(d, duration = 30, nframes = nrow(melted9)/50, end_pause = 5)
a
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to merge the dataset with the map file, if you use `geom_map` instead of `geom_polygon`.

See if this is faster for you:

```
layer_type.GeomMap <- function(x) 'point' # must run this line first

melted8 %>%
  ggplot(aes(fill = deaths, map_id = region)) +
  geom_map(map = us.map) +
  expand_limits(x = us.map$long, y = us.map$lat) +
  coord_fixed() +
  scale_fill_gradient(low = "gray65", high = "red") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  labs(title = "Deaths per Day: {closest_state}",
       x = "lon", y = "lat") +
  transition_states(date)
```

[image: result]

Dataset used (simulating 7 days of records for each state):

```
library(dplyr)

set.seed(123)
melted8 <- data.frame(region = unique(us.map$region)) %>%
  mutate(date = list(seq(1, 7))) %>%
  tidyr::unnest(cols = c(date)) %>%
  group_by(region) %>%
  mutate(deaths = abs(rnorm(n()))) %>%
  ungroup()
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like it will work!

I passed the plot to a variable A, and used
animate(A, nframes = 300)
to allow for more frames.